# Homogeneous plane containing a line and a point

Tags: vector-spaces, analytic-geometry

Say we have a line in Plucker coordinate {v|m} and a point $p$. I know that we can have a plane containing the ones with [vxp+m|-p*m], where $\times$ is a cross product and $*$ is a dot product.

I would like to know how this formula is derived.

It seems like the normal is the moment of the line around the point, but distance calculation meaning is eluding me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If we let $p=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and the line $l$ be determined by $(x_2,y_2,z_2),(x_3,y_3,z_3)$ so that its Plucker coordinates are $(x_3-x_2,y_3-y_2,z_3-z_2,y_2z_3-y_3z_2,x_3z_2-x_2z_3,x_2y_3-x_3y_2),$ then $$\{(x_3-x_2,y_3-y_2,z_3-z_2) \times (x_1,y_1,z_1)+(y_2z_3-y_3z_2,x_3z_2-x_2z_3,x_2y_3-x_3y_2)\}\cdot(x,y,z)-(x_1,y_1,z_1)\cdot(y_2z_3-y_3z_2,x_3z_2-x_2z_3,x_2y_3-x_3y_2)=0$$ is indeed the equation of the plane though $(x_1,y_1,z_1), (x_2,y_2,z_2),$ and $(x_3,y_3,z_3).$

Comment: In maxima CAS `load("vect");` `# ~ is cross product` `dot(u, v) := u[1] * v[1] + u[2] * v[2] + u[3] * v[3]$` `ratexpand(dot(express([x3-x2,y3-y2,z3-z2]~[x1,y1,z1])+express([x2,y2,z2]~[x3,y3,z3]),[x,y,z])-dot([x1,y1,z1],express([x2,y2,z2]~[x3,y3,z3])))-ratexpand(determinant(matrix([x-x1,y-y1,z-z1],[x2-x1,y2-y1,z2-z1],[x3-x1,y3-y1,z3-z1])));` `# 0 i.e. there is no difference.` This is a proof by direct verification, but not  a very enlightening one.